# how to group multiple filter selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I select first checked checkbox from div with class "site"?

I guess it should be something like that but this doesnt work:

```
$(".site :checkbox :checked :first")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the spaces

```
$(".site :checkbox:first:checked")
```

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure how the order of the pseudo selectors is checked so it would be safer to get your checked checkboxes and then run .first() on them: $(".site:checkbox:checked").first()

Comment: almost correct. should be $(".site :checkbox:first:checked")  (space between .site and :checkbox)

Comment: Yes, if `.size` is not the class of your checkbox but a parent element this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".site input[type='checkbox']:checked:first")
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/TRAk2/

Use the [Attribute Equal Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select the type of an `input`.

Comment: And what is [this](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)? Exactly, a jQuery selector named `:checkbox`

Comment: @ThiefMaster you are correct, I searched the documentation and propably I didn't see it. I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$('.site input:checkbox:checked:first")`

It searches for `input` tags that are checked checkboxes below `.site` and then returns the first element that matches these criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".site :checkbox")[0].checked);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nyus6/